# Can I use a with statement on a file that already exists?

Tags: python

I've got a file that I've already opened, and I want to auto-close it. Is there any existing way to wrap the file in a `with` statement?

Comment: What do you mean it's 'already opened'? Do you have it opened in a python shell? If you mean just a file that already exists, yes you can definitely use a `with` statement.

Comment: I dont think so how exactly do you envision this mechanic working?
how would it know when to close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine:

```
f = open('file')
with f:
    print >> f, "Open"

print f.closed  # True
```

But this will fail, as `file.__enter__` does not behave like a recursive mutex:

```
f = open('file')

with f:
    print >> f, "Open"
    with f:
        print >> f, "Open"
    print >> f, "This errors, as the file is already closed"
```

Answer (score 10):

Tested in Python 3:

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'w')
>>> with f:
...    f.closed
...    f.write('a')


False
1
>>> f.closed
True
```

So yes, you can. It doesn't reopen files that have already been closed, though:

```
>>> f.closed
True
>>> with f:
...    f.write('a')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    with f:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

---

The reason for this is likely the fact that context managers are just objects that can be used with `with` statements; the `as <identifier>` bit in a `with` statement provides an alias for the object supplied to the `with` statement so that you can create the objects in the `with` statement itself without having to put the variable declaration on another line:

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'w')
>>> with f as ff:
...    ff.closed


False
```

This makes it easy to use `with` statements on the same object multiple times (such as if the object is set up such that its `__enter__` (re)starts a connection while its `__exit__` closes the connection while allowing it to be reopened), which could be very useful for database transactions and the like.

Comment: whoa! cool I still learn new stuff... this works in 2.6 also

Comment: @JoranBeasly,GreenMatt good to know. Would've tested it on Python 2 as well but I don't have it set up on this computer and forgot about sites such as ideone until just now.

Comment: This answer just goes to show:  If you have a simple question in Python (or other similarly interactive-friendly language), why not just **TRY IT** and see what happens?

Comment: Since when did the interpreter evaluate every expression in a sequence of statements?

Comment: @Eric That was just tab fail (I tend to use IDLE for basic interactive stuff in Windows as it's slightly better-featured than the console interpreter, and it doesn't change the interpreter prompt like the console version does). Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: @JAB: What I mean was I didn't think the interpreter would print anything (your `False` `1`) if you typed a statement (like `with`), rather than an expression. Guess I was wrong

Comment: @Eric Oh, that works in the console intepreter too as long as you don't put any blank lines between the code in the block statement (because such blank lines will cause the interpreter to terminate the block).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def close_file(f):
    yield
    f.close()

with close_file(my_file):
    blabla()
```

Comment: **-1** - But that's no different to `with my_file:`

Comment: Down voting for giving yet another possible solution to a problem?

Comment: Downvoting for reinventing a wheel included in the python standard library twice, and [doing it incorrectly](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) - yours does not close the file for `with close_file(my_file): raise Exception("Whoops")`

Comment: If you want to see how to do this correctly, see the implementation of `closing` in `contextlib`, or the sample code in the PEP. Or, better, just _use_ `closing` if you want it, instead of trying to re-implement it.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're right!